# a bug in "pbcopy" using "system()" call

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

am losing my hair over this. when using the"pbcopy" in c++ using the system call it doesn't work with foreign languages unless its run in admin using sudo ???

```
system("echo привиет как дела") - works output : привиет как дела
system("echo test123 | pbcopy") - works, output to clipboard: test123
system("echo привиет как дела | pbcopy") - does not work, output to clipboard: –ø—Ä–∏–≤–∏–µ—Ç –∫–∞–∫ –¥–µ–ª–∞ 
system("echo привиет как дела | pbcopy") - using sudo to run the c++ app works, output to clipboard: привиет как дела
```

please help me out i don't want to use objective C NSPasteboard

Comment: This question isn't really about software development - it is just by chance that the user experienced this problem while developing software. I have an answer to add, if the question is reopened. Essentially what happens is that when you run that echo command without sudo, your locale settings are set to the wrong language and character set (because of your environment variables) - and when you run it with sudo, this is corrected because it then evaluates the environment of the sudo'ed user so that the character is set correct (probably to UTF-8).

Comment: incredible thanks man. i just assumed if you typed a command it would work the same. so when using the system() call you have to specify the settings of the terminal you want each time unless you use sudo in which case it uses the users terminal. get it to work by calling `echo привиет как дела |  LANG=en_US.UTF-8  pbcopy`

Comment: Exactly - that's the fix!

Comment: That sounds like a great answer, you can leave it as a proper answer so others can find it!

Comment: This will probably need a meta post and still need to be migrated away, but let's at least get up an answer @jksoegaard so we can discuss why this wasn't migrated away to SO. I don't see any way this isn't about using an API/SDK/code level problems, but let's at least get an answer up properly. I'm willing to learn if this really is terminal / shell environment related and not because C++ is calling a system library.

Comment: @bmike It is really only shell environment related - as I have detailed in my answer, the exact same thing happens when you use commands like that in the Terminal (i.e. without any programming), if you're not mindfund of your locale settings.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially what happens is that when you run that echo command without sudo, your locale settings are set to the wrong language and character set (because of your environment variables) - and when you run it with sudo, this is corrected because it then evaluates the environment of the sudo'ed user so that the character is set correct (probably to UTF-8).

This is exactly similar to what happens if you used a computer with macOS set to an English locale and input settings, and then tried to run such a command (for example from a downloaded script). Because the character set is different it would work differently.

I see the same thing often here in Denmark with conflicts over ISO-8859-1 versus UTF-8 (although UTF-8 is becoming more and more ubiquitous). If the character sets do not match, the local characters (i.e. åæø ÅÆØ) becomes garbled after piping into commands such as pbcopy.

In order to avoid this, tweak your command like this when you run it in Terminal or from a program:

```
echo привиет как дела | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbcopy
```

Setting the character set to UTF-8 means that a very wide range of characters are supported, and it matches the character set you've probably set Terminal.app to.

Comment: I propose a LANG=FTW for you @jk and user 153 - I had no idea this could be all on the shell side for environment and passed variables. Well done indeed.